# Merge Sort using Recursion in Java

Tags: java, recursion, mergesort

I am getting a stack overflow error when I run this code. I am not able to figure out the reason behind it.
The error is generated in the code : mergeSort(input,beginIndex,midIndex);
        mergeSort(input,midIndex+1,endIndex);

```
public class MergeSort {

    public static void merge(int[] input, int beginIndex,int midIndex, int endIndex ) {
        int[] temp = new int[25];

        int k=beginIndex;
        int left_end = midIndex-1;
        int num_elements = endIndex-beginIndex+1;

        while(beginIndex<=left_end && midIndex<=endIndex) {
            if(input[beginIndex]<input[midIndex]) {
                temp[k++] = input[beginIndex++];
            }
            else {
                temp[k++] = input[midIndex++];
            }
        }

        while(beginIndex<=left_end) {
            temp[k++] = input[beginIndex++];

        }

        while(midIndex<=endIndex) {
            temp[k++] = input[midIndex++];

        }

        for(int i=0;i<num_elements;i++) {
            input[endIndex] = temp[endIndex];
            endIndex--;
        }
    }

    public static void mergeSort(int[] input, int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
        if(beginIndex>=endIndex) {
            return;
        }

        int midIndex = input.length/2;

        mergeSort(input,beginIndex,midIndex);
        mergeSort(input,midIndex+1,endIndex);

        merge(input,beginIndex,midIndex,endIndex);


    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int[] array = {44,33};


        mergeSort(array,0,array.length-1);

        System.out.println("Sorted array is : ");

        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Your `int midIndex = input.length / 2;` is based only on length of input array which doesn't change so `mergeSort(input, beginIndex, midIndex);` is always invoking this method with same parameters. You need to calculate mid index based on begin and end indexes.

Comment: Recursion and StackOverlow-Errors go hand in hand. **Only use Recursion**, if your inputs are **guaranteed to be small** in size.

Comment: @Pshemo Why didn't you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @KrzysztofKosmatka I don't like to post short answers. I prefer answers with example of working solutions but I don't have time to provide it. So I decided to leave idea about problem in comment and let others do the rest :)

Answer (score 1):

You have created ever ending loop due to incorrect calculation of midIndex:

public static void mergeSort(int[] input, int beginIndex, int endIndex) {

```
int midIndex = input.length/2;

mergeSort(input,beginIndex,midIndex);//This is where issue is
```

**Correction Needed in code as below:**

```
int midIndex = (endIndex+beginIndex)/2;
```

Comment: Now there are no errors. But there is a problem in the logic. I am yet not able to find it!
If I am providing the input 55,44,33,22,11 it is returning 
44
33
55
22
11